# why I can't get value of label with jQuery and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, label

I have a usual label

```
<label class="mytxt"  style="color: #662819;" id ="telefon"></label>
```

I am **setting** a value like this:

```
document.getElementById('telefon').innerHTML = userDetails.phone;
```

after a label has some value like `"123"`.

In a **pagesource**, I have a label without setted value inside "><" but I see as output it alright:

```
pagesource: <label class="mytxt"  style="color: #662819;" id ="telefon"></label>
```

My problem is when I like to **GET** a value.
I tried *standards* like:

```
value = $("#telefon").val(); 
document.getElementById('telefon').value
```

Nothing works, value is always "not defined". Why is this so, even if I see it in the browser?

Comment: label do not have a value, only inputs do. If you want the text in a label use .text()

Comment: Use innerText; document.getElementById( 'telefon' ).innerText

Comment: `val()` and `.value` gets/sets the `value` attributes of an form element like `input`, you should use `.html()` to get inner html of `label` element, of `text()` to get text without html tags

Comment: @Speedy: I think FF doesn't support `innerText`, can use `textContent` rather.

Comment: BUT VALUE IS NEVER setted in pagesource( but i see it in browser)! its not working with any given solution

Comment: @RagimsRagimovs: Are you looking to just get the value (as in retrieve) or are you saying while viewing page source you cannot see the set value in between like `<label ..>set value</label>`?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You need `text()` or `html()` for label not `val()` The function should not be called for label instead it is used to get values of input like text or checkbox etc.

Change

```
value = $("#telefon").val();
```

To

```
value = $("#telefon").text();
```

Answer (score 9):

Label's aren't form elements. They don't have a `value`. They have `innerHTML` and `textContent`.

Thus,

```
$('#telefon').html() 
// or
$('#telefon').text()
```

or

```
var telefon = document.getElementById('telefon');
telefon.innerHTML;
```

If you *are* starting with your form element, check out the `labels` list of it. That is,

```
var el = $('#myformelement');
var label = $( el.prop('labels') );
// label.html();
// el.val();
// blah blah blah you get the idea
```